# Class with nested interface as generic type (symbol not found error in maven but works in eclipse)

Tags: java, maven, gwt-platform

I have a weird (or maybe not) problem. I am using an MVP framework and defining some of my classes in the following way:

```
public class SomePresenter extends 
    Presenter<SomePresenter.MyView, SomePresenter.MyProxy> 
{
    public interface MyView extends View {}
    public interface MyProxy extends Proxy {}
}
```

In eclipse this compiles just fine (I guess because it uses the eclipse compiler), however when I use maven (oracle jdk7 or 6) I get a *symbol not found error* for the `View` interface.

It compiles fine with maven if I do one of following things:

- put the interfaces in a separate java file
- move the import statement for `View` to the top of the import list.

Is there a know issue with using nested interfaces as generic types with the oracle java compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with the Oracle compiler, but just to make sure you could try using that in Eclipse?

More likely, I think this is a dependendy issue - show us your POM file please? Also, copy in the concrete compilation error.

The `View` interface is defined in the `com.gwtplatform:gwtp-mvp-client` artifact, which should be in there somewhere. You say that it works if you move the View`import to the top of the import list - is there another`View` in there somewhere that you perhaps need to get rid of (Ctrl-Shift-O for "optimize imports" is handy in Eclipse).

Cheers,

Comment: The dependencies are fine. I checked with `mvn dependency:tree`.
I did Ctrl-Shift-O to organize the imports and this moved the import for View down to the bottom and I get the compile error again. When I manually move the import up again it works fine with maven. I do have to try to use the normal java compiler in eclipse to check if it is related to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your POM. The key part is the dependency part. It will use the eclipse compiler.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and unfortunately I get the same error as with the normal sun/oracle compiler. Maybe eclipse (I am using Juno) is using an older compiler which can handle these circular dependencies.